# How to calculate lambdas from Bivariate Poisson distribution?

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, bivariate

I have three random variables X1, X2, X3 which follow independent Poisson distributions with parameters λ1, λ2, λ3 >0 and then the random variables X = X1 + X3 and Y = X2 + X3 jointly follow a bivariate Poisson distribution BP(λ1, λ2, λ3). If I only know
$$ P(X > Y) = constant number 1\\ P(X = Y) = constant number 2 \\  P(X < Y) = constant number 3 $$, how can I get λ1, λ2, λ3?

If it's impossible to calculate, assuming X and Y are in this range [0.001, 4], can we still get the approximated values?

Comment: Can you write those probabilities as functions of the lambdas?

Comment: I've just edited my question. If I only have those probabilities as constant numbers, can I calculate lambdas?

Comment: Naturally you would have the probability values as numbers, that's what probabilities are. To repeat: *Can you write those probabilities as functions of the lambdas?*. ... (... so, of course, you can use the numbers as the right hand sides of 3 equations in 3 unknowns, to hopefully *solve for the three lambda parameters*)

Comment: Sorry, I can't write those probabilities as functions of the lambdas. Is it the only way to solve the problem out?

Comment: I would expect this to be unsolvable generally, because your three constants must sum to unity.  Moreover, all three can be expressed in terms of $X-Y=X_1-X_2,$ showing it's impossible to find $\lambda_3:$ its value could be anything.

Comment: Indeed. The answer to my question to the OP (which I assumed they'd figure out once they proceeded to attempt to manipulate the equations) is that you don't end up with three equations in three unknowns; because each of the known probabilities involves $X-Y$ there's really only information about two of them at best.

Comment: Thank you! Since both of you have the same answer, I would consider it as unsolvable given the information.